# Hide "No data available in table"

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my table , I get the data list using json and populate this table,

```
<table id="tblClaimSearch" class="display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" id="ChkboxClaimHeader" name="ChkboxClaimHeader" value="false"></th>
          <th>Claim #</th>
          <th>Client Name</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Deduction</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Status</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                      

    </tbody>
 </table>
```

My jquery which has Json result, I get the result and append rows to table body based on my data,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ClaimResultTest", "Claims")',
            data: { seacrhClaimNumber: claimNumberToBeSearched },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                   var dataClaims = data.Claims;//This has the complete list
                   for (i = 0; i < dataClaims.length; i++) {
                    alert(dataClaims[i].ClaimNumber);
                    $("#tblClaimSearch").find('tbody')
                            .append($('<tr>')
                            .append($('<td><input type="checkbox">'))
                            .append($('<td>').text(dataClaims[i].ClaimNumber))
                            .append($('<td>').text(dataClaims[i].Client))
                            .append($('<td>').text(dataClaims[i].Amount))
                            .append($('<td>').text(dataClaims[i].Deduction))
                            .append($('<td>').text(dataClaims[i].Type))
                            .append($('<td>').text(dataClaims[i].Status))
                                )
                     }
                  }
              });
        });
```

The problem is when there is no data, I have a row displaying "No data available in table"..And even when there is data appended I still have first row as "No data available in table"..How do I hide this message row when new rows with data have been added??And secondly even though I have 16 entries it still shows "Showing 0 of o entries"?.What am I doing wrong?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication28
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "Search Name=\"search1\" BasicString=\"\" SearchText=\"\" SearchNames=\"\" SearchFields=\"\" SearchAnnotations=\"\" SearchCustom=\"\"t";
            string pattern = "Name=\"(?'name'[^\"]+)";
            string value = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups["name"].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Regex for this. Here's a small function that'll find the value after Name=

```
    public static string NameValueFromString(string input)
    {
        string returnValue = null;

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            Regex nameValueExpression = new Regex(@"name=""[^""]*""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Match match = nameValueExpression.Match(input);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                Regex valueExpression = new Regex(@"""[^""]*""");
                returnValue = valueExpression.Match(match.Value).Value.Trim('"');
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

The first Regex should find the string `Name="Something"`.
If it does then match.Success is true. The second Regex finds `"Something"` then trims the quotes off.